# How to start Jetty automatically after Apache restart on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: solr, jetty, ubuntu-14.04

I am interested in starting jetty (Solr 4.9.1) automatically after apache restart on Ubuntu 14.04 so I dont' need to manually every time I restart apache.
Could someone help me on this please?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Maven to do this? You can add the dependencies and build/run  all of them at once using maven. Or choose to just run a portion of it, its highly extensible if you know how to do it through a pom file.

Here is a link to get you [started](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/running-solr-with-maven/) .

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do this:
where:
SOLR_DIR, is the folder of the file start.jar
LOG_FILE, is where you want your log file to be
JAVA, is the path where java is installed(find it using "which java")

```
#!/bin/sh

# Starts, stops, and restarts Apache Solr.
#
# description: Starts and stops Apache Solr

SOLR_DIR="/home/humanfactor/solr/solr4"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -DSTOP.PORT=8081 -DSTOP.KEY=mustard -jar start.jar"
LOG_FILE="/home/humanfactor/solr/solr4/solr.log"
JAVA="/usr/bin/java"

    case $1 in
    start)
    echo "Starting Solr"
    cd $SOLR_DIR
    $JAVA $JAVA_OPTIONS 2> $LOG_FILE &
    ;;
    stop)
    echo "Stopping Solr"
    cd $SOLR_DIR
    $JAVA $JAVA_OPTIONS --stop
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
    esac
```

Comment: And port (8081 in our case) is the port of Jetty